# Add imageview to all viewcontrollers programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uiviewcontroller, imageview

there is a requirement like add an imageview to all viewcontrollers but I have 150+ xib's and it is time consuming to put imageview in every single xib.

Is there a common way to do it? I googled but nothing useful found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should make custom class file for image view and set.

Comment: If your are using a base ViewController you can add that programatically in that.

Comment: No I am not using base viewcontroller. Just have common xibs style

Comment: I think method swizzling!!! -> https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f

Comment: @SPatel Method swizzling has too many disadvantages and I am also using firebase

Answer (score 5):

It will be easy if you use base class like this

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController
{
   var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addImageView()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //self.view.bringSubview(toFront: imageView) //To bring imageview infront of other views put this method as per your requirement
    }
   func addImageView(name:String = "default")
   {
    let image = UIImage(named: name)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
    //view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0) /*For put image view below all image*/
   }
}
```

You need to derive all your view controller from this like this

```
class YourVC: BaseVC
```

also you can change the image with different viewcontrollers.
like

```
class YourVC: BaseVC
{
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addImageView(name:"xyz")
        }
}
```

Comment: If I add imageview on uiview and I have to add at last layer of uiview so other controls I added comes first. This seems create issue

Comment: can you provide screen shot for that

Comment: Sure, just wait

Comment: Sorry, but imgur is blocked here. But you can do it. just take a uilabel in your view and inherit that viewcontroller with base view, you will face same issue

Comment: actually i cant identify your issue

Comment: i think you want to say that if i add uilabel from derived class it will cover the uiimageview am i right?

Comment: If i add uilabel in child class so it is overwritten by uiimageview of parent class

Comment: @JitendraModi chek the updated answer this may solve your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192020/discussion-between-jitendra-modi-and-jaydeep-vyas).

Answer (score 0):

you can write an extension for UIView to add imageview into it and run it into every your viewcontrollers.

```
extension UIView {
    func addImage() {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Your Image Name")
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.didMoveToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create New `ViewController` without storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setImageView()
    }

    func setImageView() {
        let thisImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70))
        thisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "your image name")
        view.addSubview(thisImageView)
    }
}
```

now you can set this `BaseViewController` as delegate of your project's `ViewController`s.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

now you have this `ImageView` in `MainViewController` and all `ViewController`s have `BaseViewContoller` as delegate.

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.

Comment: If I add imageview on uiview and I have to add at last layer of uiview so other controls I added comes first. This seems create issue

Answer (score -2):

TL;DR No. Based on my understanding of what you are imagining, no you can't write a function to add a UIImageView to every one of your viewControllers.

Long answer:

You need to create a separate controller swift file for each View and set it up in that file. You could create a supporting file in which you setup up the the ImageView then call in in the viewDidLoad for each view controller. (You could even make this an extension of UIView so you can just call something like `self.setUpImageView()`)

My personal recommendation would be to drop the xibs as soon as you can and recreate everything pragmatically, I know it's a headache to throw all your work away but it is really worth it in the end on top of just being good practice. I have a file that I found that makes autolayout a breeze that I can share with you if you'd like. I used to really enjoy storyboards and xibs myself but they are a hassle that just isn't worth it anymore and cause such a headache in situation like this.

Comment: `drop the xibs` why??

Comment: `recreate everything pragmatically` is it cost effective?? No

Comment: It is possible with **inheritance** _or_ **method swizzling**

Comment: @SPatel Almost all apps developers that I know refuse to use story boards and most production apps do not either because it is must more robust and less time consuming